# Cygwin automatic script launch

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin, cmd

Im trying to automatically run a script using Cygwin via CMD.  I basically created a BAT file that goes to the directory and executes an .SH file.  SH files are accosiated with Cygwin, and I tried something like "cygwin update.sh" in the command line.  But all it really does is open Cygwin.  I want Cygwin to automatically run the script file.  Is there any easy way to do this, I've been trying to find but can't.  Thank you!

Comment: Another thing that could help, how can I add a file as a parameter for a Cygwin call in the CMD on Windows?

Comment: I see that you can launch any command putting it before `bash --login -i` line (last line). You can use a copy of cygwin.bat and add your stuff. Id tried `ls`and runs ok. Also tried apache start, but fails. Using bash_profiles was not an option because it's launched evertime you open cygwin. Also tried to add parameters to cygwin.bat but none of them work as i expected because the real need is to add params to bash console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to call the shell script with a particular shell, e.g. bash.

When having Cygwin open, call `which bash` to figure out where the binary is located. Cygwin also comes with tools that can convert paths between Cygwin and Win32 form, which is pretty helpful in cases like yours.

There is one other thing that may work, depending on your setup. There is an environment variable named `PATHEXT` which declares file extensions that are deemed "executable" by CMD. This can be used to your advantage, if Windows is configured so that the shell's "open" verb executes the correct shell for the file extension `.sh` (in your case).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this!

http://rothmanshore.com/2011/01/26/kick-off-a-cygwin-script-from-a-windows-bat-file-with-a-different-working-directory/

I didn't quite understand it at first, but then it worked as I wanted it.  Just if anyone knows, is there a way to make the script run without the CMD window open?? Thanks

Comment: There wouldn't be such an option, because the respective binaries to my knowledge all use the console subsystem, instead og GUI. Therefore the loader already assigns a console window if the parent is not a console application. If you want to avoid this, you'd have to start your script using `CreateProcess` and redirect the standard handles (`stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`) to pipes that you handle in your code.

Comment: oooh ok, thanks!  Ill just keep it like that without outputting to the GUI window

Answer (score 1):

From Cygwin Terminal, read `man mintty`.  Try something like the following from a Windows Command Prompt:

```
c:\cygwin\bin\mintty --hold always --exec /cygdrive/c/path/to/bash/script.sh
```